# Transform parent div without affecting its children

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am animating a zoom in effect on the outermost div tag with the class `startPageBackground`. I only want this animation to affect that div tag and not the text inside of it, and I just can't figure out a solution for it.

What I have on my start page is at first a black background page, then the main background gets loaded. When the main background is loaded, I have a script that replaces the background-image URL, and then adds a class called `backgroundZoom` to the div tag with class `startPageBackground` to start the animation. But this currently affects the children inside the div tag, and I want it to only affect the background image.

This is the Html code:

```
<div class="container-fluid startPageBackground">
    <!--Navbar overlay menu-->
    <div class="d-flex h-100">
        <div class="container justify-content-center align-self-center " style="text-align: center;">
            <a class="navbar-brand navbarBtnBrand fadeIn1" href="https://auroradev.nu">
                <img class="logoNovanik padding" src="Images/Logo659x106.png" />
            </a>
            <hr class="align-self-center fadeIn2" id="homeHR" />
            <h4 class="brodTextWhite hemParagrafText fadeIn3">Vi är specialister på kundunika mät- och testsystem, kompletta med mekanik, elektronik och datorteknik. Vår specialitet är automatiserad provning med tekniker såsom ultraljud och virvelström. Välkommen.</h4>
            <div class="container homePageButtons flex-column">
                <a class="startPageLinks rubrikText fadeIn4" href="https://www.auroradev.nu/Tjanster">TJÄNSTER</a>
                <a class="startPageLinks rubrikText fadeIn5" href="https://www.auroradev.nu/OmOss">OM OSS</a>
                <a class="startPageLinks rubrikText fadeIn6" href="https://www.auroradev.nu/Kontakt">KONTAKT</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is the code for the animation:

```
@keyframes backgroundZoom {
    0% {                    
        transform: scale(1);                      
    }

    100% {                           
        transform: scale(1.1);            
    }
}
```

Any solutions?

Comment: Using zoom will definitely affect children items, another solution you could try is to make another div be position absolute behind or inside the div containing children elements.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try with adjusting the width and also using background-size property, although I don't know if it's possible because you are only sharing a part of your code, but then you could in CSS do something like:

```
@keyframes backgroundZoom {
    0% {                    
        width: 100%;           
    }
    100% {                           
        width: 110%;
    }
}
```

while having background-size: contain; property for the startPageBackground class.

Answer (score 0):

As discovered, changing the scale of a `<div>` element will change the scale of all descendants of that `<div>`.

In order to keep the descendants from scaling, you can "de-transform" them by giving them all the reciprocal scaling of the parent `<div>`.

An example:

```js
const wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');
const content = document.getElementById('content');

function transform() {
  wrapper.classList.toggle('scale-up');
  content.classList.toggle('scale-down');
}
```

```css
/* scale up by 1.2 */
.scale-up {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}


/* scale down by 1/1.2 */
.scale-down {
  transform: scale(0.8333)
}

#wrapper {
  border: 1px dashed green;
  height: 140px;
  width: 400px;
  padding: 24px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

#content {
  border: 1px dashed gray;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 0.25rem;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<body class="pt-4 pl-5">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content">
      #content<br>
      <button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm"
        onclick="transform();">Toggle Scaling
    </button>
    </div>
    #wrapper
  </div>
</body>
```